# Creation of NSString inside if-case fails?

Tags: objective-c

I'm simply trying to decide which text I'm going with in a simple if-manner. Why does X-code complain and not let me build the project saying that the variable is undefined when it's clearly defined in the if?

```
 if(indexPath.row == [listOfItems count]) {
            NSString *cellValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Totalt: %@st registrerade", companyTotalReg]; //cellValue is unused
        } else {
            NSString *cellValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Totalt: SEK%@ intjänat", companyTotalPay]; //cellValue is unused
        }
        cell.textLabel.text = cellValue; //cellValue is undefined
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28programming%29

Answer (score 3):

You need to do it this way:

```
NSString *cellValue = nil;
if(indexPath.row == [listOfItems count]) {
    cellValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Totalt: %@st registrerade", companyTotalReg]; //cellValue is unused
} else {
    cellValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Totalt: SEK%@ intjänat", companyTotalPay]; //cellValue is unused
}
cell.textLabel.text = cellValue; //cellValue is not undefined anymore
```

Otherwise it could be that theoretically both your if clauses fail (even though this is not possible in your case) and `cellValue` remains undeclared.
As the compiler cannot know if it is theoretically possible to have all your conditions fail, so it will just warn you anyway.

In general you should/must **always initialize variables [within the scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28programming%29) in which they are about to be used**. In your case `cellValue` **would be out of scope** for `cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;`.

Kinda off topic, but [you should also use](http://cocoawithlove.com/2011/04/user-interface-strings-in-cocoa.html) `NSLocalizedString()` for any UI string, instead of hard coded ones.

Comment: Thank you very very much Regexident! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 NSString *cellValue = NULL; 

if(indexPath.row == [listOfItems count]) {
    cellValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Totalt: %@st registrerade", companyTotalReg]; //cellValue is unused
} else {
    cellValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Totalt: SEK%@ intjänat", companyTotalPay]; //cellValue is unused
}
cell.textLabel.text = [cellValue autorelease]; // The autorelease is here because you are leaking the memory otherwise. If you release the string later anyway, you can and should remove it!
```

Comment: Traditionally, the null pointer literal for Objective-C objects is `nil`, leaving `NULL` for standard C pointers (or pointers to pointers).

Answer (score 0):

The way you did it defines two NSStrings which are both named `cellValue`. The lifetime of the first `cellValue` is limited to the scope of the `if` clause and the lifetime of the second `cellValue` is limited to the scope of the `else` clause. You could resolve this in two ways:

```
NSString *cellValue;
if (indexPath.row == [listOfItems count])
    cellValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Totalt: %@st registrerade", companyTotalReg];
else
    cellValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Totalt: SEK%@ intjänat", companyTotalPay]; 
cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
```

or

```
NSString *cellValue = (indexPath.row == [listOfItems count])
    ? [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Totalt: %@st registrerade", companyTotalReg]
    : [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Totalt: SEK%@ intjänat", companyTotalPay];
cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
```

Comment: Just a clarification: the lifetime of the _names_ is limited. The objects themselves live on, and in fact are leaked.

Comment: True, the pointers' lifetimes are limited to the enclosing scope. The allocated objects live on.